# check the existence of a key in associative arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, associative-array, exists

Tell me, how correctly to check the existence of a key in associative arrays?

For example:

```
var mydata = {
    key1: '',
    key2: {
        subkey1: {
            subkey1_1: {
                value1: ''
                value2" '',
            },
        },
        subkey2: '';
    },
}

if ((mydata.key2 != undefined) && (mydata.key2.subkey1 != undefined) && (mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1 != undefined))
    mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1 = 'test';
```

Too long and confusing

```
((mydata.key2 != undefined) && (mydata.key2.subkey1 != undefined) && (mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1 != undefined))
```

I would like to use a simpler function, like

```
safeSet(mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1, 'test');
```

or

```
if (is_undefined(mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1) == true)
    mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1 = 'test'; // now - error if 'mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1' not exist
```

Comment: `associative arrays`? you mean `"object"`

Comment: Do you want to check if the key exists, or that the key has a value? Your question says the former, your code implies the latter. Either way, it sounds like you could just use `try/catch` block

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom function using `reduce()` to test if nested property exists. You can just pass key as string.

```js
var mydata = {
  key1: '',
  key2: {
    subkey1: {
      subkey1_1: {
        value1: '',
        value2: '',
      },
    },
    subkey2: ''
  },
}

function safeSet(key, data) {
  return key.split('.').reduce(function(r, e) {
    return r ? r[e] : undefined;
  }, data) != undefined
}

console.log(safeSet('key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1', mydata))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the in operator:

```
"key" in obj // true, regardless of the actual value
```

Or, if you want to particularly test for properties of the object instance (and not inherited properties), use `hasOwnProperty:`

```
obj.hasOwnProperty("key") // true
```

hope this would help you.

Source: http://www.advancesharp.com/questions/628/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript

Comment: How would `obj.hasOwnProperty("key")` be of use if the key you're looking for is several levels deep?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can make use of the `.has()` method of [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has).
Then, you would only need to check:

```
if (_.has(mydata, 'key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1')
    mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1 = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

For trying to get something in a nested structure I'd do something like this:

```
function getPath(element, path) {
    var handledSoFar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        var property = path[i];
        handledSoFar.push(property);
        if (typeof element[property] === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error('Path ' + handledSoFar.join('->') + ' is undefined');
        }
        element = object[property];
    }
    return element;
}

var mydata = {
    key1: '',
    key2: {
        subkey1: {
            subkey1_1: {
                value1: '',
                value2: 'hi'
            }
        },
        subkey2: ''
    }
};

// Prints 'hi'
console.log(getPath(mydata, ['key2', 'subkey1', 'subkey1_1', 'value2']));

// Throws error 'Path key2->subkey2->subkey1_1 is undefined'
console.log(getPath(mydata, ['key2', 'subkey1', 'subkey1_1', 'value2']));
```

Of course keeping track of the search in `handledSoFar` is optional but might be useful for development / debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the lodash deep field selector: [`lodash.get`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get) ([documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get))

```
const get = require('lodash.get');
const set = require('lodash.set');

if (!get(mydata, 'key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1')) {
    set(mydata, 'key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1', 'test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the path and make a check if the following element exist. If not assign an object to the new property.

Return then the value of the property.

At the end assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var fullPath = path.split('.'),
        way = fullPath.slice(),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r[a] = r[a] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = { key1: '', key2: { subkey1: { subkey1_1: { value1: '', value2: '' } }, subkey2: '' } };

setValue(object, 'key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1', 'test');
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the example function that you proposed:

```
safeSet(mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1, 'test');
```

or

```
is_undefined(mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1)
```

Is that the mydata.key2.subkey1... part is run *before* the function is called. So if one of the subkeys does not exist, an exception will be thrown before your code is reached.

You could get something similar using a callback though...

```
safeSet(function(val) { mydata.key2.subkey1.subkey1_1.value1 = val; }, 'test')
```

the implementation of safeSet would then be:

```
var safeSet = function(setterFunc, val) {
  try {
    setterFunc(val);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
      return false;
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

safeSet returns true if the value was set, and false otherwise.